# Screenshot in Samsung Galaxy GT-I5700

Tags: screenshot, galaxy

How to screenshot in Samsung Galaxy Spica? I already searched about it but, the answers are not accurate, so what are the buttons to be pressed?

Answer (score 1):

**General method for Android Devices**

- Reach the screen you wish to capture.
- Press and hold Power button and Volume Down button (on some devices
  with physical keys: Homescreen button and Power button) for about 2-4
  seconds, in order to take screenshot.
- You will hear a camera sound or outline frame to signal the
  screenshot being taken.
- Release the buttons, then.
- The screenshots will be then stored in the Gallery app, under the
  Screenshots folder.

[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-xv6Rt87qw)

Comment: or you may try this 
http://www.mobiwhy.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-or-screen-capture-on-the-samsung-galaxy-spica-i5700.html